# Jest how to mock environment variable in React Native react-native-dotenv

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs, mocha.js, enzyme

I am performing unit testing in React Native and when I run the test case its throwing the following error:

```
  ● Test suite failed to run
    SyntaxError: /builds/Profile.component.js: Try to import dotenv variable "PROFILE_URL" which is not defined in any .env files.
```

.env file is not available on server.

Can anyone please help me out as how to solve it in jest? I am using react-native-dotenv

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just create a .env file with your test values

Comment: @Fcmam5 .env file is in gitIgnore and it should not be available on git.

Comment: That's correct, but you can still either export `PROFILE_URL` variable on your shell, or create a local .env file on your test server which will be ignored by git. Please provide more information about this test environment and where are you running these tests, I might be missing something